# PHP MySQL Query Count the row in WHILE Looping

Tags: php, mysql

Example I have an PHP MySQL query like this :

```
$q = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM tb_post WHERE post_id = '$post_id'");
while($d = mysqli_fetch_array($q))
{
     $post_id = $d['post'];
     $uid = $d['uid'];

     if($uid != $session)
     {
     ?>
          <div>
               <?php echo $post_id; ?></div>
               <?php echo $uid;?></div>
               <br>Total Get row : ?
          </div>
     <?php
     }
     else
     {
          <div>
               <?php echo $post_id; ?></div>
               <?php echo $uid;?></div>
               <br>Total Get row : ?
          </div>
     }
}
```

Now I want when data display, it will count the row post based on UID session and not UID session.
Any idea? Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Anyone who give me -1 please comment here, whats wrong with my question?

Comment: Take a look here: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/03/08/mysql-generating-row-number-for-each-row-using-variable/ . This should help you

Comment: `based on UID session and not UID session`? whats this suppose to mean?